# Virtual Box Bridged network w/ Static IP Win7 host Ubuntu Guest

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtualbox, bridge, ubuntu-server

Last year, I had no trouble with doing the following:

- Create virtual machine
- Set network adapter to bridged adapter
- Set static IP
- Guest connects to Internet, host connects to guest @ 192.168.1.xxx

Bought a SSD, reinstalled Win7, programs etc., cannot accomplish the same.

Scenario 1: bridged adapter + leave /etc/network/interfaces left as dhcp, I can ping out from guest.

Scenario 2: bridged adapter + /etc/network/interfaces set to static, host can connect to guest, but guest cannot see WWW.

This interfaces setting used to work for me:

1. auto eth0
2. iface eth0 inet static
3. address 192.168.1.111
4. netmask 255.255.255.0
5. gateway 192.168.1.1 [or gateway 192.168.56.1]

from Vbox [not enough points for image]

1. Host-only network details
2. adapter
3. IPv4 Address: 192.168.56.1
4. IPv4 Network Mask: 255.255.255.0

Host network like:

1. VirtualBox Host Only Network
2. Unidentified Network
3. VirtualBox Host Only Network Adapter

Wireless Network Connection
myWifi
Belkin USB Wireless Adapter

I have tried abandoning the bridged adapter for NAT+Host only as I've seen in several posts like [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/434236/configure-virtualbox-guest-with-static-ip-ssh-and-internet-access-from-host), but the results are the same.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your scenario 2 and add in virtual box as a second adapter NAT, this should work

Comment: I use 1. network adapter NAT, 2nd adapter bridged and in /etc/network/interfaces
    auto eth1
    iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.1.111
    netmask 255.255.255.0