# Connect two VMs with static IPs in VirtualBox

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ssh, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I've got two instances of Ubuntu Server running in VirtualBox, mimicking a cluster we're putting together. I'll be using static IPs and communicating with SSH/MPI, which works on the real machines, but I can't get my two virtual machines to see each other. I'm seeing from [various posts](https://superuser.com/questions/434236/configure-virtualbox-guest-with-static-ip-ssh-and-internet-access-from-host/434245#434245) how this might be done, but the different network options in VirtualBox are confusing.

So far, I have:

- Set the static IPs in `/etc/network/interfaces`
- Confirmed that I have an adapter (`enp0s3`)
- If I set the VM's network to NAT, it let's me connect to the internet (download packages, etc) but not the other machine
- If I set them to Bridged (`en0: Wi-Fi (AirPort)`), I get no ping connection to either the internet or other VM

**EDIT:**
As requested, here's the output of `ip addr` on one of the nodes:

[image]

And `ip route`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use *Internal networking* to connect the hosts. Assign static addresses to the hosts so they are on the same subnet. If you need access to the internet, you could make one of the clustered machines a router with two interfaces, one connected to the internal network and the other NATed or bridged. Add a default route on the other machines pointing to the router host. Also remember to enable packet forwarding on the host acting as a router by putting the following line in `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Comment: Hmm, doesn't work for me. I have static IPs assigned to both machines (`192.168.1.6` and `192.168.1.7`). I set the network for both to Internal, which has the default name `intnet`. Am I missing a step to get them to ping or ssh each other?

Comment: What is your netmask? What is the output of `ip addr` and `ip route`?

Comment: Output posted above as screenshots. My netmask is `255.255.255.0`.

Comment: Check the addresses to see they are on the same subnet. You screen dump says 192.169.1.6, not 192.168.1.6.

Comment: [facepalm] yeah, that helped! With the internal network I can now ping and ssh between them. But I can't figure out how to get an outside connection on one of the nodes? Adding a second interface is grayed out in VirtualBox.

Comment: In the settings for the virtual machine, go to Network. If you select the second tab in the dialog, is the "Enable Network Adapter" checkbox disabled?

Comment: Oops, I needed to fully shut off the VM to add the second adapter!

Comment: If I set one machine to NAT, I get the outside internet connection but no ssh. If I do bridged I get nothing. Am I missing something?

Comment: It could be the hosts Wi-Fi adapter together with the bridged interface that's causing problems. Afaik it should work, but you never know. Incoming ssh connections with NAT are problematic due to how NAT works, but it should be possible to set up using port forwarding. See https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

Comment: Thanks Johan. Lemme dig around and see what I can figure out.